# Change admin login URL

Tags: login

I changed the admin URL from `/wp-admin` like this:

- rename `wp-login.php` to `mylogin.php`
- replace all occurrences of `wp-login.php` with `mylogin.php`

Now I can login via `/mylogin.php`.

The default page can be accessed without the extension at `/wp-admin` rather than `/wp-admin.php`.

How can I do the same so I can login via `/mylogin` instead of `/mylogin.php`?

(I'd like to do this without a plugin.)

Comment: If you're doing this for security reasons, then you are no safer than you previously were. You'll have also broken some functionality such as expired login modal dialogs and redirects. If you fix that, it can still all be undone by using the built in permalink `/login` that redirects to the login page. You'll also have broken some poorly built plugins and themes that depend on `wp-admin` for admin AJAX endpoints ( and those that work properly will reveal its location anyway ). If it's a custom login page you wanted though, there are alternatives

Comment: Tom is correct you should never do this! not only for the above reason but when you upgrade your WordPress version it could install the wp-login.php file in future version. Use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/ as this will do the work via non intrusive means and give you more control.

Comment: @TomJNowell Very interesting! Assuming I'm the only one that logs into the admin area, is it still a risk? I didn't realize plugins need access to that endpoint - why do they behave that way?

Comment: It is not worth investing time into hiding or moving the Admin or login for security as it doesn't actually improve the security. Hiding your login is "security via obscurity", which does not improve security. If you want to secure your login, use strong passwords ( 14 or more characters ), add a 2FA plugin, and add rate limiting via something like limit login attempts so bad actors get locked out after 2 or 3 tries

Comment: And until the REST API was introduced, the official method of implementing AJAX involved requests to `wp-admin/wp-admin-ajax.php`, most plugins still rely on this, and a lot of developers are unaware the REST API can handle AJAX calls

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for the explanation about the AJAX requests. I'll test my plugins to see whether they behave that way.

Comment: @TomJNowell About security via obscurity - it's not that. My server is hardened. But I'm tired of having my nginx and iptables logs overflowing from hack attempts - I can't separate the signal from the noise. If I obscure the login endpoint, they'll stop. I know this from experience of running other apps - the first thing to do is hide the login endpoint.

Comment: That's not true, bots don't check if your site is running WordPress, they just fire the HTTP request and forget. Afterall why waste the processor cycles waiting for a network reply to ident the CMS when you can fire off every exploit you have asynchronously at the same time? If you look carefully you'll even see attempts to login to Drupal and Joomla even though they're not on your server. If you have server level access, I'd consider adding sever level rate limiting so that if failed attempts happen the sender is blocked at a lower layer and never gets to interact with Nginx

Comment: @TomJNowell They do check for wordpress - I can see it in the logs. And you're right, they also check for druplal, joomla, etc. I do have rate limiting and blacklisting (via iptables and fail2ban), but it doesn't protect me from "slow attacks", and so over a 24h period, my logs are filled with cms-centric attacks from hundreds of IPs. Like I said, my server is rock solid, but the logs are hard to read, so obscuring login points makes those bots stop trying (well, at least *those* kind of attacks). I've seen this in practice, which means they are coordinated attacks from the same actor(s).

Comment: Do you not have something like fail2ban? Or a proper logging setup such as Kibana/Logstash?

Comment: @TomJNowell Yep fail2ban is in place, but there's nothing to prevent "slow attacks" from polluting the logs. I plan to setup kibana/logstash at some point. Obscuring the login endpoint was an easier win though, so I started with that :) Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

Change wp-admin login is a light plugin that allows you easily and safely to change wp-admin to anything you want. It does not rename or change files in core. It simply intercepts page requests and works on any WordPress website. After you activate this plugin the wp-admin directory and wp-login.php page will become unavailable, so you should bookmark or remember the url. Disable this plugin brings your site back exactly to the state it was before.

Go under Settings and then click on “Permalinks” and change your URL under “Change wp-admin login”.

Example: http://www.example.com/my-login.

1. Go to Plugins › Add New.
2. Search for Change wp-admin login.
3. Download and activate it.
4. Go under Settings and then click on “Permalinks” and change your URL
   under “Change wp-admin login”
5. You can change this anytime, just go back to Settings › Permalinks ›
   Change wp-admin login.

Comment: This is just a plugin recommendation, it doesn't explain how to actually do what the OP is asking. Perhaps if your answer explained how the plugin performed the technical feat the OP asks about?

Answer (score 0):

For change Login Page URL you can use "https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/" plugin.

With the help of this plugin you can change login page URL like: http://www.yoursite.com/newurl

Comment: This is just a plugin recommendation, it doesn't explain how to actually do what the OP is asking. Perhaps if your answer explained how the plugin performed the technical feat the OP asks about?